# How to create a button that consists of three image (Android) so that mid image is tiled?

Tags: android, layout

In short, I need a button that would consist of three images: left, mid and right so that depending of button text length, the mid image would be tiled.

Can someone please tell me (or provide some links) what is the fastest (maybe not the best) to get something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a button using some compound images, text and backgrounds. The fastest way I found was to make a `RelativeLayout` with the elements I needed arranged how I wanted, tiled gradient, icons etc. Then apply a click listener to the `RelativeLayout` and treat it like any other `Button` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i read it right you want i to tile the mid image..

but out of my head.. which i have not tried. here is what i will try first.

```
button.setBackground..
button.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom)
```

if you can make a tile-able background xml and set it as background. then you can try playing around the compound drawables.